# How do I distinguish between completed requests using S3 on iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, download

I am using the AWSiOSSDK to both upload and download files from the iOS environment. In both cases, the files are transferred asynchronously with the function below specifying a completed request:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
```

After the response returns a success and the file has been transferred, how do I yield what file it corresponds to? In particular, it's important that I order the downloaded files correctly. The ordering is embedded into the file names, so if possible, retrieving that in the header would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting `AmazonServiceRequest` you can set property `requestTag` to identify what file you downloaded. Also you can get `url` property to determine what file you downloaded.

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request 
didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Request tag:%@ url:%@", request.requestTag, request.url);
}
```